# Excel VBA - LCM - Sub or Function not defined

Tags: excel, vba

The following code:

```
Sub lcm_()

    If Selection.Areas.Count <> 1 Then Exit Sub

    Dim a As Range
    Set a = Selection.Areas(1)
    a.Item(1).Value = Lcm(a.Item(1).Value, a.Item(2).Value)

End Sub
```

produces the error: `Compile error: Sub or Function not defined`, and I cannot figure out why. I have looked at similar problems, and it seems like the issue is that Excel cannot find the builtin function LCM, but the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197286(v=office.15).aspx) makes it seem like it doesn't require any special libraries. I am very new to VBA, so it is entirely possible that this is something very simple, but I cannot figure out what.

EDIT:

It is worth noting that if I simply click on a cell and type `=LCM(A8,A9)`, then it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub lcm_()

    If Selection.Areas <> 1 Then Exit Sub

    Dim a As Range
    Set a = Selection.Areas(1)
    a.Item(1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Lcm(a.Item(1).Value, a.Item(2).Value)

End Sub
```

Comment: @Lerenard The key here is that you must state that you are using a native Excel function in VBA - with WorksheetFunction.{Function Name}. Note that it is generally poor practice to rely on these worksheet functions; if you are in VBA already, it is often more efficient to create functions yourself / use native VBA functions instead. In a pinch, sometimes it's best just to use these, however.

Comment: That works! Except I actually had a second error I didn't notice until you solved the first one: The second line should read `If Selection.Areas.Count <> 1 Then Exit Sub` I'll edit my question so that part is correct.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon I wasn't aware that wasn't proper practice. I'll go ahead and implement my own LCM function using Euclid's algorithm, but it's good to know why it didn't like my code.

Comment: @RohanK, why not `If Selection.Areas.Count < 1 Then Exit Sub`?

Comment: @lerenard It's not that it is necessarily a bad thing to use a worksheet function, but there are 2 problems with it: (1) any particular function optimized to be used as an Excel native function is likely either inefficient or not as accurate as what you could do if you used a VBA function [either built-in or self-created] (2) Relying on Excel native functions will deprive you of the learning gained by finding the 'VBA way' to do it. Soon, you may find that you have grown little in terms of programming knowledge, and don't have the tools to solve complex problems.